# Namespace as a parameter in a function in php

Tags: php, oop, parameters, namespaces

I'm debugging someone else's code, which actually gave me the inspiration for my code and allowed me to write a nice plugin.

The problem is that now my plugin is working fine but I don't quite understand why.

I'm trying to understand what is the benefit and the consequences of adding a namespace as a parameter to a function.

In my code, I'm analyzing this part:

```
public function check_shipping(Order $order, $option) {}
```

Where Order is a namespace that I imported in my code:

```
use Store\Model\Order;
```

And `$order` and `$option` are actually two objects, that are parameters in my function.

Just so that you know, I'm using ExpressionEngine and using a particular hook from a third-party plugin.

Essentially, my question is: what is the relationship between my namespace and the two parameters in my function?

Do the first two parameters have a relationship since there's no comma between them?

Comment: Surely Order is a class which is in a namespace,  which in the example is indicating the type that $order should be passed as.

Comment: I think (if I understand you) that the first "parameter" is actually a typehint, you're telling the PHP interperator that the first parameter passed to this function must be of type Order

Comment: It's the `Type` of the param. You should learn some strongly typed language like Java and you'll know what a `Type` really is.

Comment: [php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: I don't think there's any need to learn Java in order to understand a PHP type-hint...

Comment: I agree... learning an entire language just to grasp what a type is, is very heavy handed, just read up on types... takes about 2 minutes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this method: 

`public function check_shipping(Order $order, $option) {}`

We see that `Order` is the typehint for the `$order` parameter. `Order` and `$order` are not two different parameters.  `Order` is defining the type of `$order`.

Here is the [PHP Documentation on defining function argument types](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).  You'll notice that PHP's capabilities varies with the PHP version that you're running.   PHP 7 introduced scalar typehints such as `string`, `int`, etc but you could typehint objects since PHP 5.0 and arrays since 5.1.

`$option` doesn't have a typehint but you could add one right after the `,` depending on what its type is and your PHP version.

When defining a typehint, you can reference the full namespace: 

`public function check_shipping(\Store\Model\Order $order, $option) {}`

That way you don't have to import the namespace with a `use` declaration. (Not saying that's what you want to do in any particular situation. I'm just saying that you can do it that way)